# Unsuported grant type: Password - Spring Boot OAuth2

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

This is my config for Oauth2Authorization server

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableAuthorizationServer
    class OAuth2AuthorizationServer : AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter() {
     // Configures client app
    override fun configure(clients: ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer) {

        clients
                .inMemory()
                .withClient("client")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("password")
                .secret("{noop}secret")
                .scopes("all")
    }

    @Autowired
    private lateinit var authenticationManager: AuthenticationManager

    @Bean
    fun accessTokenConverter(): JwtAccessTokenConverter {
        val converter = JwtAccessTokenConverter()
        converter.setSigningKey(OAuth2ConfigVariables.JWT_SIGNING_KEY)
        return converter
    }

    @Bean
    fun tokenStore(): TokenStore {
        return JwtTokenStore(accessTokenConverter())
    }

    @Throws(Exception::class)
    override fun configure(endpoints: AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer) {
        endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore())
                .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
                .accessTokenConverter(accessTokenConverter())
    }


}
```

This is my curl request

```
curl client:secret@localhost:8080/oauth/token -d grant_type=password -d username=user -d password=pwd
```

---

I'm always getting

```
{
 "error" : "unsupported_grant_type",
 "error_description" : "Unsupported grant type: password"
}
```

---

Answer (score 0):

hope to help you!
Maybe you should add parameters in http request Authorization.
For example:

1. username:xxx (This is client id,in your project is "client")
2. password:xxx (This is client secret,in your project is "{noop}secret")
3. the type is "Basic Auth"
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UENqb.jpg)

postman ^-^

Answer (score 0):

The problem here was in line:

```
 .secret("password")
```

The word **password** needs to be encrypted in order to work.

I thought that the function will do it but it's not the case I guess.